# How to get last messge between two friends in the messge table having id in descending order?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Hi friends help me to solve this problem ," display all last messages of a user from all his/her friends"

My sample message table is

```
---------------------------------------------------
|  id | msg       | sender |  reciver | friend_id |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1  | Hi        | 1      | 2        | 1         |
|  2  | Hi..      | 2      | 1        | 1         |
|  3  | Hello     | 6      | 1        | 3         |
|  4  | What dong | 1      | 6        | 3         |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I need only the last message b/w the user and his friends (here consider user id is 1)

I need the result like below , please help me to achive this with mysql

```
---------------------------------------------------
|  id | msg       | sender |  reciver | friend_id |
---------------------------------------------------
|  4  | What dong | 1      | 6        | 3         |
|  2  | Hi..      | 2      | 1        | 1         |
---------------------------------------------------
```

The name of this table is message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.msg, a.sender, a.receiver, a.friend_id
from msg a
left join msg b on (a.friend_id = b.friend_id and a.id < b.id)
where b.id is null
  and (a.sender = 1 or a.receiver = 1)
order by a.id desc;
```

Can be tested at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35823/10

It uses "groupwise-max" solution with a left join as can be found for instance in [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) (last example).

Your schema seems a bit weird keeping sender, receiver and friend_id, but I suppose friend_id is a FK to some friends table where pairs of (1,2) and (1,6) are stored, so it is more of a "friendship_id" ?